# How to plot grid of images in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I am able to plot images using `image_summary_t = tf.image_summary('data', x, max_images=1)` and this plots 'max_images' number of images but I want to plot images as a grid, something like 3x3 grid of images.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the **family** parameter of `tf.summary.image(name, family='...')` to group several images into one part.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/image for more details.